# TinyMCE Shortcuts - Custom shortcuts appear to be overwriting each other

Tags: tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen a ton of questions about TinyMCE shortcuts, but nothing quite like this.

I have a situation in which I am iterating over an object of shortcuts I want to add to TinyMCE.
The shortcuts add functionality for the greater app around the editor.

For the most part, it works fine.
However, it appears that I cannot add certain combinations. For example, `alt+l` and `alt+left`.

Take this code:

```
_.each(oHotKeyCollection, function (oHotKey, sHotKey) {
    this.editor.addShortcut(sHotKey, oHotKey.note, function (e) {
        if (!e) {
            e = event;
        }
        // sHotKey is the pattern (ie. alt+l)
        alert(sHotKey)

        oHotKey.execute(e);
    }.bind(this));
                }
}.bind(this));
```

When `alt+l` is added, and then `alt+left` is added, hitting `alt+l` on the keyboard will bring up an alert with `alt+left`.

Removing the `alt+left` shortcut allows `alt+l` to function as expected.

The same behaviour seems to be true of `alt+r` and `alt+right` as well as `alt+u` and `alt+up`.

How I can get both shortcuts working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that only certain keywords can be used in a shortcut, such as the modifier names (ctrl, alt, etc...). Anything else is treated as a single key so `left` in this case isn't valid and is treated as just being `l` (see [Shortcuts.ts](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/eae627190ef2a71cce7123565562c40b7bd0daf1/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/Shortcuts.ts#L87)). That's why `alt+l` is being overridden with your `alt+left` behavior.

So to fix that, you'll need to use the keycode for `left` instead of a keyword. In this case that would be `alt+37`. Here's a fiddle showing that working by printing to the console: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/EEhaab.

Since you also mentioned you're trying to register other arrow keys, here's the key combinations you'd need to use:

- Left: `alt+37`
- Right: `alt+39`
- Up: `alt+38`
- Down: `alt+40`

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you!